ggplot cutting off state border lines
I'm trying to create a map around Arizona and Sonora featuring political border lines for both the US and Mexico. I've created data frames for the US and Mexican borers using geodata. These seem to plot jsut fine onto my google-derived base map at low zoom. The issue arises when I restrict the x and y limits to zoom in on my area of focus. The border lines don't extend to the end of the zoomed in plot. It's almost like the boundaries of the ggplot don't actually extend to the full extent of the base map. Any idea what's happening here, or how I can fix it? Also, unfortuntely my code requires an API key so you might not be able to run it all if you don't have one. Apologies!
library(maps)
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)
library(geodata)



options( geodata_default_path = "C:/PATH")

#Download USA Spatial Vector Data
USA <- geodata::gadm(country = "USA", level = 1, version = "latest")

#plot border spatial vector
plot(USA, xlim = c(-124.732453,-66.983690), ylim = c(24.445430,49.39), col = "lightyellow")

#draw a box around the plot
box()

#set coords for the extent
coords <- list(x=c(-124.732453,-66.983690), y = c(24.445430,49.39)) #extent determined by

#create the new extent
New_extent <- extent(coords)

#clip the spatial vector to the new extent
USA <- crop(USA, New_extent)

#plot the clipped spatial vector
plot(USA)

#duplicate the spatial vector
country <- USA

#turn the spatial vector into a spatial polygons dataframe
country <- as(country, "Spatial")

#convert spatial vector to dataframe
country_map <- fortify(country)

#download USA spatial vector data
Mexico <- geodata::gadm(country = "Mexico", level = 1, version = "latest")

#plot border spatial vector
plot(Mexico, xlim = c(-120, -85), ylim = c(33, 15), col = "lightyellow")

#draw a box around the plot
box()

#set coords for the extent
coords <- list(x=c(-120,-105), y = c(25,33)) #extent determined by

#create the new extent
New_extent <- extent(coords)

#clip the spatial vector to the new extent
Mexico <- crop(Mexico, New_extent)

#plot the clipped spatial vector
plot(Mexico)

#turn the spatial vector into a spatial polygons dataframe
Mexico <- as(Mexico, "Spatial")

#convert spatial vector to dataframe
Mexico_map <- fortify(Mexico)



#set API
ggmap::register_google(key = "YOURKEY")

#Create a satellite map centering over the study area
base<-get_map("Nogales, Sonora", source="google",maptype="satellite",zoom=5)
ggmap(base)

#Add political border lines for the US and Mexico
base<-ggmap(base)+
  geom_path(data=country_map,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group),size=0.1)+
  geom_path(data=Mexico_map,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group),size=0.1)
base

Here's the zoomed out map. Just to clarify, I know that not all Mexico's borders are drawn. For my purposes, I only need Sonora's state border lines.

#restrict the x and y axes to zoom in on the study area
base.zoomin<-base+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-116.5, -107))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(27, 38))
base.zoomin 


And here's the zoomed in map. Notice that the border lines don't extend to the edges of the map. Is there any way for me to fix this issue? I realize it's not a huge deal, I'm just trying to create a hgh quality map. Thanks!


Figured it out, just had to add expand = c(0, 0) to the scale_x_continuous() and scale_y_continuous() functions.
